# Hide errors during mysql import

Tags: mysql

I was wonder if anyone knows how I can hide errors while running a mysql import from the Windows command line.  I am doing,

mysql -u root -p < db_import.sql

However if I get an error like "ERROR 1060 at line 1: Duplicate column name `field2`" is there a way that I can stop these from showing?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
mysql -uroot -ppass --force < db_import.sql
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I still got an error message displayed.  Could there be something else I am doing run.  By the way I am running mysql 5.0.51